# Is there a single function "do-not-optimize" attribute that can be used with Microsoft Visual Studio compilers?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have this macro for GCC and CLANG working just fine

```cpp
#if defined(__clang__)
#define BENCHMARK_DONT_OPTIMIZE [[clang::optnone]]
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__GNUG__)
#define BENCHMARK_DONT_OPTIMIZE [[gnu::optimize(0)]]
#elif defined(_WIN32)
#define BENCHMARK_DONT_OPTIMIZE __pragma(optimize("",off))
#else
#define BENCHMARK_DONT_OPTIMIZE
#endif
```

However for MSVC I tried all possible combinations of `__pragma(optimize("",off))` and even `#pragma optimize("",off)` to no avail. It seems that although msvc accepts both syntaxes, it does not process them according to their documentation.

For the test below, the MSVC assembly looks exactly the same, while for both GCC and CLANG they collapse that first implementation with the trivial `N(N-1)/2` formula.

```cpp
template< typename SumType >
struct Sum {
    SumType operator() ( SumType size ) {
        SumType sum  =  0;
        for ( SumType j=0; j<size; ++j ) {
            sum += j;
        }
        return sum;
    }
};


template< typename SumType >
struct SumNoOpt : public Sum<SumType> {
    BENCHMARK_DONT_OPTIMIZE  SumType operator() ( SumType size ) {
        SumType sum  =  0;
        for ( SumType j=0; j<size; ++j ) {
            sum += j;
        }
        return sum;
    }
};

template struct Sum<size_t>;
template struct SumNoOpt<size_t>;
```

What exactly I'm doing wrong here?

Full test on [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/drMaT3qGv)

Comment: MS pragma is file level annotation - Any function below pragma line won't be optimized

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Microsoft specifically states in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/optimize?view=msvc-170 that you CAN turn it off and on: `#pragma optimize( "", off )
/* unoptimized code section */
#pragma optimize( "", on )
`

Comment: @VladFeinstein Sure. But it is still file level annotation, no a statement level one. As soon as it appears somewhere in the c++ file, everything above would be optimized, but everything below won't.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I did some more research and this looks like true. Write as an answer and I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#pragma optimize("",off)** as well as __pragma and _Pragma variants are not statement, but file level annotations.

It should appear in the source file, somewhere between functions and (assuming optimized build) everything above would be optimized and everything below would be not, till the end of file or **#pragma optimize("",on)** annotation.

Realistically, this is the only way to debug VC++ application - full debug build is not a good workable approach - way too slow to load, run and debug, and too much memory use on top of that. So, release build and sprinkle this pragma in the suspicious file(s), and debug